# CLU and CQA integration with Bot Framework Composer

Tags: bots, botframework

I am facing problem while integrating both CLU and CQA configurations under the same root dialog.

Hi All,

I have created an empty bot in composer and added CLU and CQA individually and the integration was successful. Now I want to use both CLU and CQA together and I am trying to add the confugurations under the same root dialog. Can you please help me out how to achieve this scenario.